# CodeMirror 2: How to filter out xml attributes?

Tags: xml, filter, codemirror

Is there a way to modify CodeMirror or XML mode definition script to enable filtering of few attributes that user shouldn't see on screen?

So I just want to find that attributes and give them new class that is set to 'display:none'

For example...

before:

```
<sample1 xns:id="e7b014d9-6271-4e32-921d-7488edfd6ea4">a</sample1>
<sample2 xns:id="d3450e86-7264-4512-9891-6c7183257741">b</sample2>
<sample3 xns:id="7f04f178-f235-4647-8584-c4e77f73fecf">c</sample3>
```

after:

```
<sample1>a</sample1>
<sample2>b</sample2>
<sample3>c</sample3>
```

And I don't want to delete attributes from XML itself I just want to hide them, because I need them when I convert editing result back to XML object.

Comment: This is not how CodeMirror works. It's a code editor, it doesn't hide parts of the text from the user.

Comment: I know it's not how it works. But I want it to modify it to work like that.

Comment: Version 3 has been released and it is now possible to do [inline code folding](http://codemirror.net/demo/folding.html) (i.e. only hide part of a line). I'm sure you could set up a plugin to automatically hide attributes you don't want to look at, and only see them when you want to edit them.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use xslt to convert schema into format you want. Not replace file but generate anather with hiden attributes.

Comment: Can you post a little sample of your method? Because my main problem is to convert newly generated file back to original form with attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my C# code to do the job. You can easily modify it into JavaScript.

```
public static string RemoveAttributes(
        string xmlString)  {
  string retXML = null;
  XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
  xDoc.LoadXml(xmlString);
  XmlNode root = xDoc.DocumentElement;
  if (xDoc.DocumentElement != null) {
     XmlNodeList list = xDoc.SelectNodes(@"/");

     if ( list != null ) {
        RemoteAttributes(list);
        retXML = root.OuterXml;
     }
  }

  return retXML;
}

private static void RemoteAttributes(XmlNodeList list) {
  if (list != null ) {
    foreach (XmlNode node in list) {
      if (node.Attributes != null) {
        node.Attributes.RemoveAll();
      }
      if (node.HasChildNodes) {
        RemoteAttributes(node.ChildNodes);
      }
    }
  }
}
```